# BlockingSPID is 0 - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, deadlock

What does it mean when all BlockingSPIDs are 0?
I'm trying to troubleshoot deadlocks with this [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/find-blocking-processes-using-recursion-in-sql-server-2005/275) but not getting any results.

Thank you.

The errors I'm getting look like this:

[image]

Comment: Your linked article is about blocking, not deadlocks. Which are you experiencing? Are you seeing error messages like `Transaction (Process ID %d) was deadlocked on %.*ls resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is currently being blocked.

You need to capture the deadlock graph or trace flag output to troubleshoot deadlocks. Not look at `sys.sysprocesses`.

See [How to Track Down Deadlocks Using SQL Server 2005 Profiler](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/) or [Detecting and Ending Deadlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Doing a trace is not an option for me now. Any other ways to troubleshoot?

Comment: @Becky - Not really (unless you know both the queries involved?) Just to be clear though turning on a trace flag `DBCC TRACEON (1204, -1)` is not related to performing a SQL Server trace

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks for clarifying that. So, what effect would a trace flag have? This would be the production server.

Comment: @Becky - It dumps the deadlock output to the SQL Server error log. As an example of the format [see this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx). I should have suggested `1222` actually as less cryptic. Would have thought performance implications minimal as it only has to do anything when a deadlock actually occurs.